# How to improve performance of two chained aggregations in neo4j query

Tags: neo4j

Assuming I have a neo4j graph of the nature:

[image]

```
create (SK:Author {name:'Stephen King'}), (JK:Author {name:'J.K. Rowling'}), (DS:Author {name:'Dr. Seuss'}), (TS:Book {name:'The Stand'}), (HP:Book {name:'Harry Potter'}), (CH:Book {name:'Cat in the Hat'}), (SHINING:Book {name:'The Shining'}), (PAF:Genre {name:'Post-Apocalyptic fiction'}), (F:Genre {name:'Fantasy'}), (C:Genre {name:'Childrens'}), (HORROR:Genre {name:'Horror'}), (SK)<-[:WRITTEN_BY]-(TS)-[:CATEGORIZED_AS]->(PAF), (JK)<-[:WRITTEN_BY]-(HP)-[:CATEGORIZED_AS]->(F), (DS)<-[:WRITTEN_BY]-(CH)-[:CATEGORIZED_AS]->(C), (SK)<-[:WRITTEN_BY]-(SHINING)-[:CATEGORIZED_AS]->(HORROR)
```

Neo4j console link: http://console.neo4j.org/r/2d69kq

I have about 53,000 author nodes, 6 million book nodes, and 9,000 genre nodes.

For a query like:

```
match (b:Book)-[:WRITTEN_BY]->(a:Author)
where a.name in ['Stephen King', 'J.K. Rowling']
with a, collect(b) as bs
unwind bs as book
match (g:Genre)<-[r:CATEGORIZED_AS]-(book)
where id(g) in [13, 14, 15, 16]
with a, count(distinct book) as book_count_author, collect(book) as bs
unwind bs as book
match (g:Genre)<-[r:CATEGORIZED_AS]-(book)
where id(g) in [13, 14, 15, 16]
return a.name, g.name, count(distinct book) as book_count_genre, book_count_author
```

It takes roughly 12 seconds to complete. I've tried to rewrite the query a few different ways and use index hinting, but can't figure out any ways to make it any faster. Any thoughts? Obviously this example is simplified, but I do have indexes on the appropriate properties.

Here's a sample result from the chained aggregations:
[image]

I need two aggregations. The first one is count of books by authors, constrained by the specified genres in the 2nd match. The second count is of books by each author in each genre, again constrained by the same genres.

Comment: Your ids are not portable for those of us attempting to recreate this on our own systems (neo4j internal IDs should never be used externally, as they may change, and ids can be reused by the system). Please modify your query to not use ids for matching.

Comment: Can you also show your schema for indexes and constraints?

Comment: Re: ids, you can use the linked neo4j console, which should keep the ids. This isn't my real schema, but is representative. I can't share the real schema. I do have indexes on the columns being used and don't see any scans in the execution profile.

Comment: So let me see if I understand your requirements...book_count_genre should be the number of books TOTAL in that genre, regardless of author, and book_count_author is the number of books in that genre written by the given author?

Comment: The table I included is what I expect for results. book_count_author is total number of books written by the author within all constrained genres. book_count_genre is the count of books by genre and author, within all constrained genres.

Comment: I'm still having a little trouble comprehending. So for the Stephen King - Horror, book_count_author is the number of books Stephen King has in the Horror genre, and book_count_genre is the count of all Horror genre books?

Comment: book_count_author for Stephen King in this case is the total count of books across all constrained genres, so post apocalyptic fiction and horror. the count of 2 on both rows is the same count value. book_count_genre is the count of books per author per genre. so if S.K. had another horror, it would be 2.

Comment: how many authors and genres are you passing in in your real query?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an index (or existence constraint) on :Author.name, you can probably use this:

```
match (book:Book)-[:WRITTEN_BY]->(a:Author)
where a.name in ['Stephen King', 'J.K. Rowling']
with a, book
match (g:Genre)<-[:CATEGORIZED_AS]-(book)
return a, g, size((g)<-[:CATEGORIZED_AS]-()) as book_count_genre, count(book) as book_count_author
```

Collecting and unwinding can be expensive, try to avoid it where you can. Note that you can find the size of a pattern to get a count of the pattern that would otherwise not be retrievable by a count on a node given your columns.

EDIT

Modified query for clarified requirements

book_count_genre - the number of books with that genre by any author

book_count_author - the number of books with that genre written by the given author

Comment: Not sure this works, as I need book_count_author to be constrained by the (Genre)<-[:CATEGORIZED_AS]-(book) pattern.

Comment: Perhaps you can add to your description exactly what kind of output you want, and how it's meant to be constrained. A query can only show what you've tried, but may not be able to fully capture intent.

Comment: You're right, sorry, I've edited by description to describe the 2 counts that I need. Both counts need to be constrained by the specified authors and genres.

Comment: I modified my query, it should work with your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

What @InverseFalcon said.

You can optimize it a bit further:

```
MATCH (g:Genre)<-[r:CATEGORIZED_AS]-(book:Book)-[:WRITTEN_BY]->(a:Author) 
WHERE a.name in ['Stephen King', 'J.K. Rowling'] 
  AND g.name IN ['Post-Apocalyptic fiction','Childrens','Horror','Fantasy'] 
WITH a, g, count(distinct book) as  book_count_author_genre 
RETURN a.name, collect({ genre: g.name, count: book_count_author_genre}), 
       sum(book_count_author_genre) as book_count_author
```

You might need to use index-hints for authors and genres

If you use id's for lookup it will be faster.